# Windows 7 - Favorites folders in the My Computer window

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise. When I click on a favorite folder (left hand pane) in a **My Computer** window, it opens into a new window even though I have the folder options set to "open each folder in the same window".  Is there anyway to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Love it when people suggest conflicting things on forums... 
These things are  all claimed to solve your problem!

Suggestion 1:

> Have a look at this registry key and
>   check that it says: None
>
> ```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell
> ```

Suggestion 2:

> My Fix:
>
> open "regedit" (Start/Run...)
>
> go to
>
> "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell"
>   and change the (Default) field to
>   "open" (without the quotes)
>
> Ready!

Suggestion 3:

> 1- open the registry editor (Winkey+R
>   and type in "regedit")
>
> 2- Navigate to
>   HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3831040691-3390046849-3855596486-1000\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
>
> 3- Find the "Explorer" key and delete
>   it, it will be then recreated.
>
> 4- Reboot
>
> ** Please keep you should always back up
>   your registry before you make registry
>   edits. Also, this is something I found
>   through a Google search and although
>   people have reported it works for them
>   I can't be sure as I haven't tried it.**

Last resort:

http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/regs_edits/settingssamewindow.reg

or

http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/regs_edits/opendefault.reg

Comment: yep, says "none"

Comment: Following suggestion #2 fixed the issue for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue was that the explorer always gets launched with My Computer in the breadcrumb bar. This seems to break all kinds of things including opening each folder in it's own window by single clicking and breaking the breadcrumb bar itself, but the solution is simple (no registry edits required):

1. Right click on 'windows explorer' icon on the taskbar
2. Then right click 'Windows Explorer' item in the jump list *again*.
3. Then choose properties
4. Then on the shortcut tab change target from:

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /root,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}

to:

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe c:

That makes explorer start in C: which avoids the whole problem.