# Windows 7 - make folders from favorites open in new window

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, favorites

By default if I click on a folder in "favorites" (left hand pane), they open in the same window, as normal folders. But for latter I can hold ctrl while double-clicking to open them in new window. Obviously I can't do that with left hand pane, and the only option for me is to open their context menu and "open in separate window", which is bothersome.

I found a question where they discuss the case when [favorite folders open in new window, while normal folders open in the same](https://superuser.com/questions/93120/windows-7-favorites-folders-in-the-my-computer-window). They give the solutions to fix this problem, but they don't tell about what causes such behavior (which registry settings are used to enforce it).

I'd like to know, how to modify registry to attain such behavior.